# Reduction modulo a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-algebra, grothendieck-topologies

I am looking at the following part of a paper:

[image]

$$$$

[image]

---

$$$$

When we reduce the differential equation $(1)$ modulo the prime $p$ we do the following: 
$$\alpha_i \equiv \tilde{\alpha}_i \pmod p$$ 
So $$(1)_p : \tilde{\alpha}_0 (x) y^{(n)}+\tilde{\alpha}_1 (x) y^{(n-1)}+\dots +\tilde{\alpha}_n (x) y=0$$

right?

What does it mean that we reduce the differential equation $(1)$ modulo the prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ ?

Isn't the prime ideal a subset of a ring?

Comment: It is reduced modulo the prime ideal $\mathfrak p$, not $p$ (which does not generate a prime ideal).The operation consists in reducing the coefficients of the polynomials  $a_i(x)$, which belong to the ring of algebraic integers of $K$, modulo $\mathfrak p$.

Comment: A prime ideal is a set, or not? When we reduce it modulo the prime $p$, which is a number, we reduce each coefficient $c_i$ of $\alpha_i $ by $c_i \equiv \tilde{c}_i \pmod p$, right? Could you give me an example how we reduce modulo a prime ideal? @Bernard

Comment: In a field of characteristic $p$, we have $p=0$, so it amounts to not reducing whatever. And, yes, a prime ideal is a set. So what? Almost everything is a set in maths, even natural numbers.

Comment: Why not name the paper?

Comment: What do you mean by "it amounts to not redung whatever" ? I haven't understood how we can redulo modulo a set... @Bernard

Comment: The name of the paper is "Algebraic Differential Equations". @Hoot

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the operation that is performed is this: the coefficients 
of the polynomials $a_i(x)$ belong to the ring of algebraic integers $A$ of an algebraic number field $K$. For any prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $A$, we can consider the quotient ring $A/\mathfrak p$, which is an integral domain and has  a field of fractions, which is called the residue (class) field. Alternatively, we can consider the localisation $A_{\mathfrak p}$ of $A$ at $\mathfrak p$, which is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}$, and its residue field $\,A_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}$.

In short, we reduce each coefficient of the $a_i(x)$ modulo the prime ideal  $\mathfrak p$, in the same way as we reduce a polynomial ideal with integer coefficients modulo a prime number.